# WPA with PSK and with Radius Server

Tags: wpa2, wpa2-psk, wpa2-eap

In case of WPA2 using the Radius server, every client gets its own username and password. But what is the case in the WPA2 using a PSK without the authenticating server. In this case also we have a 4 way handshake. But is the PTK derived by all clients different or the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PTK is derived by all clients by using the following attributes: PMK (Pairwise Master Key), AP nonce (ANonce), STA nonce (SNonce), AP MAC address, and STA MAC address. That means that a different PTK will be derived for each 4 way handshake, although the PSK is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So in that case, what is the added advantage of WPA2 with the radius server. Is it just for the authentication of the client?

Comment: With RADIUS, you eliminate the use of shared passwords.

Comment: One last confusion I have is at the end of the Radius EAP-TLS authentication, a master key is shared with the client/access point. But what is the use of this key in the 4 way handshake. Is the PTK generated using this master key?

Answer (score 1):

> But is the PTK derived by all clients different or the same?

- Short answer: **YES**.
- [Longer answer](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/network-director1.1/topics/concept/wireless-wpa-psk-authentication.html):

> With WPA-PSK, you configure each WLAN node (access points, wireless
>   routers, client adapters, bridges) not with an encryption key, but
>   rather with a plain-English passphrase that contains up to 133
>   characters. Using a technology called TKIP (Temporal Key Integrity
>   Protocol), that passphrase, along with the network SSID, is used to
>   generate **unique encryption keys for each wireless client.**

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So in that case, what is the added advantage of WPA2 with the radius server. Is it just for the authentication of the client?

Comment: @AnkurBhatia Yes, RADIUS is just an **authentication** protocol suitable for you in case you have to manage lot of clients unlike when you use WPA2 with PSK

Comment: Thank you begueradj. One last confusion I have is at the end of the Radius EAP-TLS authentication, a master key is shared with the client/access point. But what is the use of this key in the 4 way handshake. Is the PTK generated using this master key?

Comment: @AnkurBhatia Please ask that [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) because it is a different question from your main one and it is hard to explain it through a comment.