# Dynamic Key Management in WPA through Radius server

Tags: authentication, key-management, radius

Can anybody tell me in detail (or provide good links), how the dynamic key management is done by the authentication server in WPA? In other words, let's say I gave my credentials to the authentication server in EAP RESPONSE / IDENTITY, then how does the server process further things like generating the master key, pair-wise master key, finally to session key (which algorithm are they using to generate these?). I looked in the following sources, but didn't find the exact answer:

[Using dynamic keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/using-dynamic-keys)
[WPA with PSK and with Radius Server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94178/wpa-with-psk-and-with-radius-server)